# I want to put Entities into Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

I want to put Entities into Firebase.I use Dialogflow of Google.
I want to put name Entities into Firebase database.

Now my Javascript code is

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential:admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL:'ws://app-name.firebaseio.com/',
});
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; 
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function handleName(agent) {
    const name = agent.parameters.name;
  }
 
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I run my code,and write words to DialogFlow,but no data is in Firebase.I think my code is wrong but cannot understand what is wrong.
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shown has at least two problems with it:

1. Although you have a `handleName()` function, which appears to be an Intent Handler, you're not registering it as a Handler in your `intentMap`.
2. Your `handleName()` function isn't doing anything with the name. In particular, its not trying to save it in Firebase.

To address 1, you would need to add a line such as

```
intentMap.set('Name Intent', handleName);
```

Addressing 2 depends on your firebase structure, but might be something like

```
  function handleName(agent) {
    const name = agent.parameters.name;
    const ref = admin.database().ref('path/to/where/to/store/name');
    return ref.set( name )
      .then( () => {
        agent.add("Data saved. What next?");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can understand what you are saying,but I cannot write code what you are saying.Would you write example code?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some examples, but exactly what you do is *highly* dependent on what your'e trying to do, and you haven't really made that part clear. So you may wish to consult the documentation about how to save values in Firebase, try them, and if you're still having problems, ask a new question illustrating what you've tried and what doesn't work.